# SwiftUI List didSelect like in UITableView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a list that shows country image, name and phone code and I want to know which country is selected, like in **UITableView** `didSelectRowAt indexPath`

**LocaleInfo**

```
struct LocaleInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let dialCode: String
    let code: String

    var flag: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "Countries.bundle/Images/\(code.uppercased())", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)
    }

}
```

**SwiftUI**

```
List(filterLocaleInfo.filter({ $0.name.hasPrefix(search) })) { info in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: info.flag ?? UIImage())
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(info.name)
                        .font(.custom("Avenir-Medium", size: 17))

                    Text(info.dialCode)
                        .font(.custom("Avenir-Book", size: 15))
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { self.getLocaleData() }
```

Answer (score 5):

SwiftUI does not have a didSelectRowAt or anything similar because it works with states rather than standard event handlers for changes.

You should define an `@State` variable which will track the currently selected value:

```
@State private var selectedLocale: LocaleInfo? = nil
```

then use the [`init(_:selection:rowContent)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/init(_:selection:rowcontent:)-3pchc) constructor:

```
List(filterLocaleInfo.filter({ $0.name.hasPrefix(search) }), selection: $selectedLocale) { info in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: info.flag ?? UIImage())
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(info.name)
                        .font(.custom("Avenir-Medium", size: 17))

                    Text(info.dialCode)
                        .font(.custom("Avenir-Book", size: 15))
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { self.getLocaleData() }
```

where `$` sign before the variable means you bind the `@State` variable to the List's selection value, meaning that the `selectedLocale` variable will contain at all times the currently selected locale, and whenever this state variable changes, the entire view will be recalculated (given that you actually use this state variable somewhere else - for example in an `if` statement).

Comment: When I try this approach, the `@State` value stays `nil`, even on selection?

Comment: This approach doesn't work before iOS 16 ‘cause `selection:` is only available in EditMode.

Comment: This constructor still exists, so I am afraid that is not true: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/init(_:selection:rowcontent:)-3pchc